# How to check if value exist in a json array javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, reactjs

I have the following Structure:

```
_id: 'blog',
    posts: [
      {
        _id: 'politics and economy',
        name: 'politics and economy',
        author: 'Mark',
      },
      {
        _id: 'random',
        name: 'random',
        author: 'Michael'
      }
    ]
```

**My if Statement**:

```
if(posts.name.includes("politics"){
//Doing Stuff
}
```

How Can I get this running? I do not know the length of the Array.

Comment: You can use the array filter method https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter to get the items from the array that match your criteria.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check if an array includes a value in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-a-value-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to know the length, you can use `forEach`

```
posts.forEach(post => {
    if(post.name.includes("politics")){
        //Doing Stuff
    }
});
```

Comment: you miss a ')' in the if statement

Comment: @JohnSneijder You are right (I've copied/pasted the code from the question) It has been corrected. thx

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [method some](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_some.asp) to check if one of the posts has the value

```
var name = "politics";
posts.some(singlePost => {
     return singlePost.name == name;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the array filter method. [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(posts.filter(post => post.name.includes("politics")).length > 0){
//Doing Stuff
console.log("One of posts has a name including politics")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const posts = [
      {
        _id: 'politics and economy',
        name: 'politics and economy',
        author: 'Mark'
      },
      {
        _id: 'random',
        name: 'random',
        author: 'Michael'
      }
    ]

posts.forEach(post => {
if(post.name.includes("politics")){
//Do Your Stuff
console.log(post.name)
}
});
```

You have to loop through the posts array.